# Adding beams of light effect using adjustment layer

Tags: premiere, effects

I have filmed a green screen sequence where a figure acts like he walks through a doorway. The effect I want to achieve with the green screen is to make it look like the figure is walking into pure energy / light. Here is my workflow thus far:

- I have placed the empty scene at the bottom of the timeline layers.
- Above that I added the same scene (but this time with the figure).
- Then I replaced the green background with a solid layer of white.

However, it looks a bit dull and I wanted to make the 'pure energy' look more convincing by adding a burst / beam of light effect. Similar to below:

[image]

### Question

How do I achieve the effect where the beams of light appear to shine both behind and above the figure?

Comment: Have you tried the tutotial by andrew kramer?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frXQxwMKh6c